# Loading data into single excel file using loop in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to send email to multiple agent.For this i am using for loop for iteration.
I am new in SSIS.I want to load single excel file using loop in ssis.but after first execution,this is showing error.i.e. file is already in use.Please help

Comment: are you using a script task by chance? if so, then you need to close the file or use a using statement.

Comment: Yes I am using script task.Can you please help me  foor this?

Comment: can you post code you are currently using? I'll adjust it in an answer. Make sure to remove IPs and passwords etc.

Comment: there are two ways to handle this. Either loop in your script task or close the file on every loop iteration. Your current issue is the 2nd pass is trying to open a file for write that is already open. Unless you specifically tell a script task to close a file, it will remain open until the package completes.